# É possível autenticar um usuário em múltiplos serviços?

Tags: php, session

Tenho dois serviços distintos um do outro, mas ambos compartilham do mesmo dados para autenticação, sendo assim, fiz uma tela de única para entrada que te dá as opções do serviço que o usuário final deseja entrar. Ao entrar ele passará por uma validação e ganhará um nome de sessão que será recuperada na página inicial do serviço escolhido.

Na index de cada serviço faço a recuperação da variável de sessão, para recuperar esses dados utilizo a variável do servidor, mais especificamente `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` aonde recupero a página passada para recuperar em si a sessão do mesmo.

Basicamente é uma gambiarra que funciona até certo ponto, pois ao dar refresh na página, a variável do servidor fica vazia, por não ter uma referencia concreta de onde ele saiu, sendo assim não posso usa-la para autenticar o usuário. Com meu conhecimento atual não vejo outra maneira de fazer essa autenticação em ambos serviços.

Gostaria de entender uma forma melhor de fazer essa autenticação, se devo ou não seguir fazendo dessa forma, qualquer opinião é válida.

Para facilitar a compreensão, disponibilizei em blocos cada página com breve código para dar coesão a tudo que expliquei acima.

**PÁGINA AUTENTICAÇÃO**

```
  $some_name = session_name("some_name");
  session_set_cookie_params(360, '/', '.digiapp.com.br');
  if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

  $_SESSION['userId'] = $row_1->id_diretora;
  $_SESSION['userNome'] = $row_1->nome_diretora;
  $_SESSION['userEmail'] = $row->email_diretora;
  $_SESSION['userPass'] = $row->pass_biblioteca_diretora;
```

**PÁGINA DE SERVIÇO 1**

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://login.digiapp.com.br/' || $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://login.digiapp.com.br/index.php'){
    $some_name = session_name("some_name");
    session_set_cookie_params(360, '/', '.digiapp.com.br');
    session_start();
}else{
    // Destrói a sessão por segurança
    session_destroy();
    // Redireciona o visitante de volta pro login
    header("Location: ../index2.php"); exit;
}
```

Comment: Você quer compartilhar a sessão (com todos os dados que possam estar nela) ou apenas a autenticação?

Comment: Com todos os dados, mas o problema não é esse, eu consigo recuperar os dados na index de cada serviço, mas não consigo mantê-los após um refresh, pois a variável `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` perde a referência que tinha antes, sendo assim ele não recupera mais a sessão pelo nome da sessão, pois não passa na validação. Você pode ver na página de serviço 1 como estou realizando a recuperação da sessão

Comment: Mas se você consegue recuperar na index, você pode neste momento, colocar outro critério para manter a sessão ativa no refresh. Você pode por exemplo, criar uma variável 'ativa' na SESSION e testar no if:
if($_SESSSION['ativa'] || $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://login.digiapp.com.br/' || $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://login.digiapp.com.br/index.php'){

Comment: Certo, mas a sessão só é recuperada dentro do IF, sendo assim a página não carregará, pois fiz a referência antes da sessão ser carregada. Já pensei em varias formas, criando cookie, validando por url...Mas sem sorte

Comment: olha, recomendo usar um serviço de autenticação que possa ser "compartilhado" como o OAuth, tem fácil integração com PHP, vai limitar os dados que tem sessão, mas é uma opição de mercado que funciona bem e integra fácil ao PHP